# Do I need outlets in a built-in bookshelf?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

I know that there is normally an outlet every 6 feet rule for electrical code.

However, I am doing a renovation in which an entire wall is a giant bookshelf and cabinet built in which is 17 feet wide. Do I need to somehow get outlets into the cabinetry?

Comment: Outlet every 12 feet, not 6. Such that no floor device along the wall requires a cord longer than 6 feet

Comment: If the cabinetry doesn't lend itself to having outlets installed, you could also consider putting some in the floor or the baseboard right near it.

Comment: Related, and seemingly answers in the negative: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/82794/nec-6-12-rule-clarification

Comment: Seems like you'd want one or two outlet just in case you, in the future, wanted to add a light or two...

Comment: Even if you don't technically need them, your future self (or a future owner of the property) will thank you for putting them in anyway. I've seen that happen dozens of times...

Answer (score 3):

I read the 2017 code (clause `210.52(A)(2)(1)`) as such:

> ... a wall space shall include ... any space 2ft or more in width and ... unbroken along the floor line by ... fixed cabinets that do not have countertops or similar work surfaces.

This says to me that walls on either side are to be treated separately, not that the cabinet requires outlets as though it was wall space. Therefore, you aren't required to fit outlets into your cabinet.